# read txt file with some data missing

Tags: r, rdata

I do realize similar questions have already been posed, but given that none of the answers provided solves my problem, frustration is beginning to set in. The problem is the following: I have 27 identically shaped time series data (date, Open, High, Low, Last) in txt format and I want to import them in R as .txt file in such a way that the first line read is the one with all 5 data. Example given below shows that while the data in text file starts on 1984-01-03, I would like for the file to be read from 1990-11-05 (since Open is missing for earlier dates), save first column of dates as rownames and save other 4 columns as numeric with the obvious name for each of the column.

```
            Open    High    Low     Last
1984-01-03         1001.40  997.50  997.50
1984-01-04         999.50   993.30  998.60

1990-11-05  2038.00 2050.20 2038.00 2050.10
1990-11-06  2055.00 2071.00 2052.20 2069.80
```

Given that this is a common problem, I have tried the following code:

```
    ftse <- read.table("FTSE.txt", sep="", quote="", dec=".", as.is=TRUE,   
               blank.lines.skip=TRUE, strip.white=TRUE,na.strings=c("","NA"),
               row.names=1, col.names=c("Open","High","Low","Last"))
```

I have tried all sorts of combination also with specifying colClasses, header=TRUE and other commands (for fill=TRUE the data is actually read, but this is exactly what I dont want) but I always get the following error (or the number of the line in error message is different)

```
    Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
    line 1731 did not have 4 elements
```

Line 1731 is the one corresponding to the date 1984-01-03. I am kindly asking for help, since I can not afford to lose any more time on such issues, so please provide suggestions how I can fix that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the general solution might be but a combination of readLines and read.fwf might work in your case:

```
ftse.lines <- readLines("FTSE.txt")
ftse.lines <- ftse.lines[ftse.lines != ""] # skip empty lines
ftse <- read.fwf(textConnection(ftse.lines), widths=c(11,8,8,8,8), skip=1, row.names=1)
names(ftse) <- c("Open", "Hi", "Lo", "Last")
```

You may need to modify some parts but it works with your example.

The following (using just read.fwf) also works:

```
 ftse <- read.fwf("FTSE.txt", widths=c(11,8,8,8,8), col.names=c("blah", "Open", "Hi", "Lo", "Last"), skip=1)
```

And then try to convert the first col to rownames if that's really needed.